# Custom SearchView return empty results

Tags: django, django-haystack

I am trying to do filter using custom SearchView, here is my code:

```
sqs = SearchQuerySet().filter(content='Testing')
view = search_view_factory(
    view_class=SearchView,
    template='search/results.html',
    load_all=True, 
    form_class=None,
    searchqueryset=sqs,
    )
return view(request)
```

But it keeps on giving me No results found although when printing the sqs, I do get result.

AnyIdea what could be missing in my code ??

Comment: Are you using whoosh? I've experienced something similar - it seems there's a bug with whoosh, of which I haven't got to the bottom. I ended up switching to Xapian for my last project.

Comment: yes I was using whoosh. And I switched to Elasticsearch eventually.